# p2p port restricted<->port restricted

Tags: nat, p2p

Есть клиент A и B(оба за port restricted NAT), сервер S(белый ip)

1. A и B подключаются к S
2. S сообщает клиенту A ip:port B, клиенту B ip:port A
3. A посылает пакет B
4. B посылает пакет A
5. Клиенты могут общаться напрямую

Однако при тестах, на некоторых port restricted NAT возникали непонятные ограничения:

1. A посылает пакет B, B пакет A => общение возможно, но если B
   посылает пакет A, A пакет B => на B приходят пакеты с другого порта
   A(общение в таком случае невозможно)
2. A посылает пакет B, B пакет A => пакеты идут только к A, но если B
   посылает пакет A, A пакет B => A и B НЕ получают пакеты

Из-за чего возможно такое поведение???

Comment: Напрашивается ответ, что "так работают NAT'ы перед A и B". Такими их сделали, такие у них правила фильтрации пакетов. Что вы хотите услышать?

Comment: @D-side, мне известно 4 вида NAT, только с пробивом Symmetric ожидаются проблемы, если провайдеры могут крутить на свои NAT любые ограничения, то зачем вообще эти самые NAT классифицировать?

Comment: Спросите тех, кто их вообще так классифицирует. [Есть несогласные](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150298/).